# AngularJS Dynamic Filtering Performance

Tags: angularjs, report, filtering, angularjs-filter

In my AngularJS web app I have several table views where I allow users to filter on the data using search terms. I am currently doing that dynamically (i.e. when a user starts typing the data starts filtering). I know this can potentially render slow result time if there were thousands of rows in my table.

Is filtering is this way frowned upon and do I really need to be concerned about this performance issue?

Comment: If you have thousands of rows in a table generated by Angular, you'll have performance issues with the table itself, whether you use a filter or not.